# Can I use visio as an output for information stored in a database, so that I can select filters to render different content into visio objects?

Tags: database, visio

Can any one tell me if I can use visio as an output for information stored in a database, so that I can select filters to render different content into visio objects?  Or is there a microsoft product that can do this?

I am unable to find a product that appears to do this

Comment: Very interesting and most probably feasible. Would mind elaborating on the details? What to filter, how, how big, ...

Comment: Thank you.If you imagine I have a car production line consisting of 100 stages; attaching the wheels on the car, inserting the windshield, etc. would each represent a stage.This can be modeled in a flow diagram.I want to be able to click a given 'stage' in the flow diagram and then any information associated with that stage would be provided by a filter, so one filter could be names of installers, another could be manufacturer of e.g. windshield, etc. This represents a lot of info that changes so would need administration via a DB but the number of 'pages' to display this data would be <500.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I have misunderstood, this the very basic of what Visio does.
It would take too long to explain all the possible options in detail, but in summary:

- there are assistants in Visio that help you connect to a datasource (Access, Excel, ODBC, ...)
- these assistants draw automatically the desired diagram. If the some special case is not covered, you can easily use some code - eg VBA - to draw the diagram by yourselves.
- the diagrams are dynamic
- you can see the data connected to a stage shape either in the custom data window, or you can add automatic labels - smart datagraphics
- you can even export to the web to show the results in a web browser.

Some videos on youtube found very quickly:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TBSW6-r7AZ8&ab_channel=Microsoft365
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o6VMKo7_KgY&ab_channel=ComputerTutoring
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xfIPFiAxQcQ&ab_channel=FarazShaikh
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0FDq596M7KA&ab_channel=ITsEasyTraining1st

I can give you more detailed help here (file exchange is easier and great community): http://visguy.com/vgforum/index.php